# Is help still valid when using movement after it?

Tags: dnd-5e

In a situation were a rogue uses help as action, disengage as bonus action and movement to move away, does he still help another PC to attack the target with adv?

Comment: We've marked your question as a dupe because it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one.

Comment: Oh, and Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!